# Using animation nodes, how do I set the origin to the center of each object in an object list?

Tags: animation-nodes, origin

I'm a beginner with animation nodes, trying to make a delayed falloff animation with a grid of hexagons. I've figured out how to make them rotate around a single origin (at world center), but can't set each object's origin to the center of the object so it rotates around itself. What series of nodes or settings do I have to add or adjust to make each hexagon rotate on its own axis?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]
[image]

motivation:

[image]

further infos:
https://docs.animation-nodes.com/release_notes/v2_0/id_keys/

Comment: Man I had no idea how far away I still was. Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You are welcome!